# swift: Label in collectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have 7 sections and 3 cels in section in my collectionView.

My code to download file when cell was clicked:

```
enum DownloadStatus {
    case none
    case inProgress
    case completed
    case failed
}
struct item {
    var title : String!
    var downloadStatus : DownloadStatus = .none

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

var downloadQ = [Int: [Int]]()

typealias ProgressHandler = (Int, Float) -> ()
var items = [[item]]()
var tableId = 0
var onProgress : ProgressHandler?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

items = [
        [item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2")],
        [item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2")],
        [item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2")],
        [item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2")],
        [item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2")],
        [item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2")],
        [item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2"),item(title: "item 2")]
    ]
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return media.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return media[section].count
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

var item = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
                    downloadQ[indexPath.section]?.append(indexPath.row)

                    var theArray = downloadQ[indexPath.section] ?? [Int]()
                    theArray.append(indexPath.row)
                    downloadQ[indexPath.section] = theArray

                    // Create the actions

                    let url = URL(string: "link")!

                    let downloadManager = DownloadManager()
                    downloadManager.identifier = indexPath.row
                    downloadManager.tableId = indexPath.section
                    downloadManager.folderPath = "folder"
                    let downloadTaskLocal =  downloadManager.activate().downloadTask(with: url)
                    downloadTaskLocal.resume()

                    var cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell
                    cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell
                    cell.label?.isHidden = false

                    downloadManager.onProgress = { (row, tableId, progress) in

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

                            if appDelegate.masterVC == nil {
                                return
                            }

                            if appDelegate.masterVC.tableId != tableId {
                                return
                            }

                            let indexpath = IndexPath.init(row: row, section: indexPath.section)
                            var cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell
                            cell = appDelegate.masterVC.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexpath) as! MasterViewCell

                            cell.label?.text = "\(CGFloat(progress))%"

                        }

                    }
}
```

My Download manager class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension URLSession {
    func getSessionDescription () -> Int {
        // row id
        return Int(self.sessionDescription!)!
    }

    func getDebugDescription () -> Int {
        // table id
        return Int(self.debugDescription)!
    }
}

class DownloadManager : NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {



    static var shared = DownloadManager()
    var identifier : Int = -1
    var tableId : Int = -1
    var folderPath : String = ""
    typealias ProgressHandler = (Int, Int, Float) -> ()


    var onProgress : ProgressHandler? {
        didSet {
            if onProgress != nil {
                let _ = activate()
            }
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func activate() -> URLSession {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!).background.\(NSUUID.init())")

        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
        urlSession.sessionDescription = String(identifier)
        urlSession.accessibilityHint = String(tableId)

        return urlSession
    }

    private func calculateProgress(session : URLSession, completionHandler : @escaping (Int, Int, Float) -> ()) {
        session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (tasks, uploads, downloads) in
            let progress = downloads.map({ (task) -> Float in
                if task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive > 0 {
                    return Float(task.countOfBytesReceived) / Float(task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive)
                } else {
                    return 0.0
                }
            })

            //print("tbale id \(session.accessibilityHint ?? "hit")")

            let stringNumb = (session.accessibilityHint ?? "hit")
            let someNumb = Int(stringNumb as String) // 1357 as integer

            let string1 = (session.sessionDescription ?? "hit")
            let some1 = Int(string1 as String) // 1357 as integer

            if let idx = downloadQ[someNumb!]?.index(of: some1!) {
                downloadQ[someNumb!]?.remove(at: idx)
                //print("remove:\(downloadQ)")
            }

            completionHandler(session.getSessionDescription(), Int(session.accessibilityHint!)!, progress.reduce(0.0, +))
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){

        let stringNumb = (session.accessibilityHint ?? "hit")
        let someNumb = Int(stringNumb as String) // 1357 as integer

        let string1 = (session.sessionDescription ?? "hit")
        let some1 = Int(string1 as String) // 1357 as integer

        if let idx = downloadQ[someNumb!]?.index(of: some1!) {
            downloadQ[someNumb!]?.remove(at: idx)
            //print("remove:\(downloadQ)")
        }

        let fileName = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        var destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appending("/\(folderPath)"))


        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURLForFile, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            destinationURLForFile.appendPathComponent(String(describing: fileName!))
            try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
        }catch(let error){
            print(error)
        }



    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

        let stringNumb = (session.accessibilityHint ?? "hit")
        let someNumb = Int(stringNumb as String) // 1357 as integer

        let string1 = (session.sessionDescription ?? "hit")
        let some1 = Int(string1 as String) // 1357 as integer

        if let idx = downloadQ[someNumb!]?.index(of: some1!) {
            downloadQ[someNumb!]?.remove(at: idx)
            //print("remove:\(downloadQ)")
        }

        if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
            if let onProgress = onProgress {
                calculateProgress(session: session, completionHandler: onProgress)
            }
            let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
            //debugPrint("Progress \(downloadTask) \(progress)")

        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {

        let stringNumb = (session.accessibilityHint ?? "hit")
        let someNumb = Int(stringNumb as String) // 1357 as integer

        let string1 = (session.sessionDescription ?? "hit")
        let some1 = Int(string1 as String) // 1357 as integer

        if let idx = downloadQ[someNumb!]?.index(of: some1!) {
            downloadQ[someNumb!]?.remove(at: idx)
            //print("remove:\(downloadQ)")
        }

        //debugPrint("Task completed: \(task), error: \(String(describing: error))")
    }

}
```

But I have a problem. My app crashes in this line - cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

with this issue: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. How to fix it?

Comment: You must save the progress value, instead of only saving downloadTaskLocal you should create a download object for each download and save to your array. Each download object will be responsible for downloading a task. In the download object keep all the downloading info. like progress and etc. so that on creating cells access this array to set values.

Comment: @vivekDas I update question. And add new code under Update title. How to fix it?

Comment: **Never ever** call `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForItemAt`. It **cannot** work. Unlike in `cellForItemAt` you are not able to return the cell to the framework.

Comment: use like -> as?

Comment: @vadian Sorry. I don't understand how to fix a problem. Could you tell more about this? Maybe you can show example?

Comment: @vivekDas `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10270ba1c)`

Comment: You are manipulating the **view** (the cell) without updating the **model** (the data source array). You have to make your changes in the model and reload the row to update the view in `cellForItemAt`

Comment: @vadian How to do it? How to reload row? In cell class?

Comment: No, in the controller class.

Comment: @vadian I need to use this `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)`?

Comment: Yes this reloads a row and calls `cellForItemAt`

Comment: @vadian Sorry for a lot of questions. I should use this line `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)` before which line? And I should  make my changes in `items `?

Comment: You won't solve the problem just by calling `reloadRows` somewhere. You have to refactor your design to save and change the progress value and the properties related to the progress indicator in the model. After changing the value(s) reload the row

Comment: @vadian Oh, I have code in `cellForItemAt` to update progress. I not add this code to question because I have error in `downloadManager.onProgress = { (row, tableId, progress) in`. How to fix this error?

Comment: @vadian If I never call `dequeueReusableCell` in `downloadManager.onProgress = { (row, tableId, progress)` how to I show progress? Or I should use `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)`  in `downloadManager.onProgress = { (row, tableId, progress)` and it call `cellForItemAt `?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is due to cell reuse. Each time you scroll in your collection or table, you usually deque the old cell. Which means whenever you are displaying new cell `cellForRow`(table), or `itemForRow`(collection), you'll have to have data for the cell to be able to feed it.

If you only store the data about your download process into the cell you'll lose them at the moment when `prepareForReuse:`, system call, gets called, because the cell gets reset.

The other way around would be to use static cells. Because the static cells, never gets reset. But that's handy only when you use a small number of items on the screen. If you have tens or hundreds of cells, then it gets very costly on performance.